# ForMember setting does not working when using AutoMapper in .Net Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper in my .NET Core project. The default mapper function is working well, but when I use `.ForMember()` in `myProfile.cs` class, it doesn't work.

`myProfile.cs` just like :

```
public class ServiceProfile : Profile
{
    public ServiceProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Organization, OrganizationDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Active, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Disabled));
    }
}
```

The configuration in `startup.cs` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
        mc.AddProfile(new ServiceProfile());
    });

    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Then

```
input.Disabled=0;
var output = _mapper.Map<Organization>(input);
```

I expect the output.Active to be 0, but the actual output is null.

UPDATE:

I'm sorry, the method has no problem, it's because I'm using dapper and skip the map step.

Comment: Try specifying the full generic overload, e.g. `_mapper.Map<Organization, OrganisationDto>(input);`

Comment: Then you should delete this question.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve that? adding `ReverseMap()` didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because the mapping method is `CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>`, source is the first generics parameter, but in the code below your mapping is from the DTO class to organization class (in the other direction) for which the mapping is probably not specified.

You may need to create mapping also for the other direction from `OrganizationDto` to `Organization`.

Update: there now is an easy way to add mapping for the other direction by adding `.ReverseMap()` to the end of `CreateMap` call chain.